# XSS code returned in Source Page

Tags: web-application, appsec, xss

I am trying to understand XSS. I have basic understanding of reflected, stored XSS and how they should work. In this particular case the code that i inject is getting returned in the source of the page but I do not get any prompt/pop-up like the usual alert.

Say I inject `<script>alert("XSS")</script>`

But i can see the string that I passed return in the source. Is it possible to exploit it? is this behavior secure?

Can anyone please help me understand this.

Comment: Are you using any add-ons like NoScript?

Answer (score 1):

I think probably the XSS is mitigated using Response Headers like

1. X-XSS-Protection
2. Content-Security-Policy
3. X-Content-Type-Options

You can read more about these Headers [here](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Secure_Headers_Project) . If these headers are implemented properly, the injected script will not be executed as Javascript by browser and prevents XSS.

Comment: For the sake of completeness, giving link here on how to mitigate - https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet

Comment: Also wondering can html/javascript escape come in play here?

Comment: Why do these headers prevent the script from executing? Please expand your answer to explain.

Answer (score 0):

Try same scenario on Mozilla Firefox.
I think you are using chrome, it has a functionality to block JavaScript popup